# What is the difference between mozilla and webkit touch events?

Tags: javascript, events, webkit, touch, mozilla

I've been reading in the last couple of days about touch devices and events.

I've seen lots of scripts that make difference between webkit and mozilla touch events?

What is the main difference between them, as I couldn't find out anything from their websites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main difference is  `gesturechange` events vs. `touchchange` events 
For example Android uses `touchstarst` while iOS uses `gesturestart` for detecting "finger on screen".

This [blog post](http://backtothecode.blogspot.com/2009/10/javascript-touch-and-gesture-events.html) describe these differences. 
I would use a framework like Sencha or jQuery Mobile to solve all x-device issues.

Comment: A thousand upvotes to you sir, I went to Apple's "Documentation" to no  avail: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/WebKitDOMRef/TouchEvent_idl/Classes/TouchEvent/index.html